# DbgEng.dll - нет интерфейса "IDebugOutputCallbacks"

Tags: winapi, callback, windbg, dbgeng

Всем привет!
В своём приложении я импортирую библиотеку отладчика **DbgEng.dll**, чтобы воспользоваться её методом `IDebugControl::Execute`. Нашёл в гугле примеры где говорится, что перед вызовом "Execute" нужно зарегистрировать процедуру обратного вызова `IDebugClient::SetOutputCallbacks`, параметр которой наследуется от метода `IDebugOutputCallbacks::Output`.

Ладно, что всё слишком запутано, но я проверил три версии библиотек DbgEng.dll (WinXP/7/10), но ни в одной из них интерфейс `IDebugOutputCallbacks(2,3,Wide)` не реализован. Пробовал даже брать не штатную библиотеку из папки system32, а из поставки отладчика WinDbg (которая по размеру больше), но и в ней отсутствует данный интерфейс. Думал может GUID не верный передаю - специально скачал хидер "dbgeng.h" из SDK-10 - результат тот-же. Может кто знает, в чём тут дело, и как решить проблему?

Для тестов написал утилиту для обхода всех интерфейсов, где нули обозначают ошибку `E_NoInterface = 0x80004002`. Система "Win7-x64, Build: 6.1.7601". Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это callback интерфейс, который должен реализовать в своем классе пользователь библиотеки, то бишь вы.

Comment: @user7860670 - вот оно в чём дело. Значит `IDebugBreakpoint` тоже входит в эту категорию?

Comment: Быстрый взгляд показывает, что для создания `IDebugBreakpoint` есть фабричный метод `IDebugControl3::AddBreakpoint`.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое - очень помогли разобраться в теме.

Comment: @user7860670, ещё вопрос.. Если интерфейс `IDebugOutputCallbacks` не реализован, то зачем ему свой guid.. в каких целях и где я должен использовать этот guid? Да, есть примеры на с++, но я программирую на ассемблере fasm, поэтому что-то не получается переписать его на ассм.

Comment: У кадого COM интерфейса должен быть GUID, так как должна быть возможность получить этот интерфес через `IUnknown::QueryInterface`.

Comment: @user7860670, ну так в том-то и дело, что `QueryInterface` с гуидом `OutputCallback` у меня всегда возвращает нуль. На скрине выше я так и перебирал все интерфейсы.

Comment: `QueryInterface` с гуидом `OutputCallback` будет возвращать успех, только когда указатель на интерфейс `IUnknown` указывает на экземпляр класса, который реализует этот интерфейс. Перебирать все интерфейсы у какого-то одного объекта - очень сомнительная затея.